# Is there any way to play Bukkit plugins in Single Player without having to make my own server?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, mods

I'm just wondering if there was any way I could install [this mod](http://dev.bukkit.org/server-mods/minecraft-last-airbender/) into my single player minecraft client so that I would be able to play a singleplayer world with this mod.

Comment: Is there a single player version of that mod?

Answer (score 7):

No. There's an important distinction between Multiplayer *mods* and Craftbukkit *plugins*. All SMP mods are automatically compatible with Singleplayer Minecraft and are installed in the same way, but Bukkit plugins are designed specifically for the custom server called Craftbukkit. Minecraft can only launch its *own* built-in server, so there's no way (I know of) to have it run Craftbukkit instead when you click "Singleplayer".

However, running craftbukkit locally is totally doable. It won't slow down your machine more than playing singleplayer normally does, because singleplayer runs a hidden server anyway. When you play on a local Craftbukkit server, Minecraft doesn't bother launching its own singleplayer server, so it ends up being the same amount of stuff running on your computer. Of course, you still have to set up the Craftbukkit server and install the Last Airbender plugin properly, but that's doable with some reading and learning. Once you have a multiplayer server running locally, you just use the Multiplayer button, add a server at the `localhost` address, and have fun.

Answer (score 2):

There is a way to do this, using BukkitForge. This basically allows you to put Bukkit... inside Forge, the mod loader.

If you want to watch a video tutorial on how to do this, [here is one](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X6ZgkJq-XXw). [Here is also a text tutorial](http://forums.technicpack.net/threads/bukkitforge-getting-bukkit-plugins-on-tekkit-lite.34804/). Or you can just read this:

First, you have to install [Minecraft Forge](http://www.minecraftforge.net/forum/). This also allows you to install other Forge mods, like Computer Craft, Industrial Craft, and even more!

Now, install this by going to the download section, download the recommended version, and then copy the files in the zip into your minecraft.jar ([instructions](http://www.minecraftforge.net/wiki/Installation/Universal)).

Run your Minecraft to make sure it works. Forge will set up, and then you should be good. Now it is time to install [BukkitForge](http://build.technicpack.net/job/BukkitForge/). Download `BukkitForge-Latest.jar`, and then put this file into your mods folder (if your on Windows Vista, 7, or 8, click Start, type `%appdata%`, go to the `.minecraft` folder, then there should be a folder called `mods`.

Place the BukkitForge file from before into this folder, and start Minecraft. It should start up normally. Now, go back into the `.minecraft` folder, like before, and there should be a folder called `plugins`. If there isn't one, create it now.

Now all you have to do is put your JAR file from the plugin you want to install into this folder, run Minecraft, load up a world, and bam, the plugin should work.

Have fun :)

Answer (score -1):

Use the BetterLan mod: it lets you use Bukkit plugins in Singleplayer.

You can also use RealLan mod, but it will not support plugins, only add new commands.

Comment: BetterLAN does not work. I tried it and most plugins like Essentials give an error. The plugin itself uses a modded 1.6.4 CraftBukkit when you download the 1.5.2 version of it. I do like BetterLAN because it is able to broadcast a CraftBukkit server through LAN.

Answer (score -1):

Actually, there is a way.as one of you said,when minecraft single player is launched, mc has its own server. Mc uses mods, where as bukkit uses plugins. Its a very long and extremely difficult process, but if you go into your minecraft files (for most computers just search %appdata%/.minecraft in the files) you can switch what minecraft thinks mods are, into plugins so it will think plugins are mods thus you changed the way minecraft thinks  mods are. I myself have never done it, but i know its possible.

Comment: Hi @jalen1563, do you think you could fix the spelling? Because that hunk of text makes no sense. (Also, to point out - There's a mod that allows you to run Bukkit as your single-player server)